# ¿Como puedo cambiar la imagen de un servidor de Discord? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy creando un **bot multifunciones**, que pueda hacer muchas cosas y quiero agregar un comando para cambiar la imagen de un servidor pero la imagen que ya este predefinida por ejemplo, este es el codigo que llevo:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def change_icon(ctx):
  image = "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/711356150741991424/940806535842508850/gato_uwu.jpg"
  icon = image.read()
  await bot.edit_guild(ctx.message.guild, icon=icon)
```

Pero tengo el problema que dice que

> .read no puede leer str

**Y pues puedo tener la imagen guardada para leerla ?** si, pero no se me hace util para mi caso asi que si alguien sabe como puedo cambiarla con un link estaria agradecido de antemano

Comment: debes hacer una llamada a la url. ejemplo:  `icon= urllib.request.urlopen(image)`

Comment: @Bryro con la libreria request o cual ?

Comment: con request seria `icon= requests.get(image, stream=True).content` o `icon= requests.get(image, stream=True).raw`

Comment: @Bryro Me salen estos dos errores 
`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es agregar la libreria **urllib.request**, y luego importarlo `from urllib.request import Request, urlopen`

**El codigo quedaría asi:**

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def change_icon(ctx):
    image = Request("https://imgur.com/xMPYOjO.jpg")
    icon = urlopen(image).read()
    await ctx.guild.edit(icon=icon)
```